# Using self as the first argument in ruby instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is [`String#dasherize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-dasherize) from `ActiveSupport::Inflector`:

```
def dasherize(underscored_word)
  underscored_word.tr('_', '-')
end
```

It replaces underscores in a string with dashes.

```
'puni_puni'.dasherize # => "puni-puni"
```

The receiver is used as the only argument for the method.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.dasherize(puni_puni) # => "puni-puni"
```

When I try to do something similar, it doesn't work:

```
module NewDash
    def new_dasherize(underscored_word)
        underscored_word.tr('_', '-')
    end
end

String.include NewDash

t = "t_e_s_t"
t.new_dasherize # => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
t.new_dasherize(t) # => "t-e-s-t"
```

How can I replicate this behavior, and what is the technical term for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a couple different ways. LcLk mentioned one way, by setting `self` as the default for `underscored_word` in your argument list. Another way would be by referencing self directly

```
module NewDash
  def new_dasherize
    self.tr('_', '-')
  end
end

String.include NewDash
```

After running that, you can call `new_dasherize` directly on the string itself

```
>> 'puni_puni'.new_dasherize
=> "puni-puni"
```

You can achieve the exact same thing, `ActiveSupport` style, with this

```
class String
  def new_dasherize
    self.tr('_', '-')
  end
end
```

That's what ActiveSupport does, open the `String` class ([check it out](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb#L9)) and tack on some methods. They just happen to delegate the implementation of this `dasherize` method to `ActiveSupport::Inflections`

If you look [Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L185), you'll see where `ActiveSupport` actually implements their `dasherize` method.

The technical term is probably "extending an object", though I'm not positive on that.

Answer (score 5):

try to write like this

```
def new_dasherize
  tr('_', '-')
end
```

Its same as `self.tr('_', '-')`, where `self` is a `String` class instance in this case.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a magic way of doing this. If you look inside [core_ext/string/inflections](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb#L125) you can see that active support reopens the String class and does

```
class String
  def dasherize
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.dasherize(self)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the conventional way of doing this is, but what you are essentially looking for is to make `t` an optional argument to your `new_dasherize`, and to give it a default value of `self` when it isn't supplied.

```
module NewDash
  def new_dasherize(underscored_word = self)
    underscored_word.tr('_', '-')
  end
end
```

This is a rather pointless default as it only works if `self` is a string like object which responds to `tr`. I would suggest adding some validation or type casting, or at least solid documentation to explain the specific use case of your module.